# Set default drill down field for specific Chart

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Clicking a bar in a chart allows doing a drill down in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. But it always prompts for a field to do it.

Is it possible to set a default drill-down field?

Say, for example, I have a "Customers by Country" chart and naturally expect drill-down to be by `City`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cant.  There is very little you can customize about charts outside of the fetchXML or with the chart designer in the UI.